# Grunt: How to change config strings for different environments

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a python file as part of my grunt workflow. I have defined two build tasks:

- build:dev
- build:release

When I compile 'build:dev', I want to add this line to my python file:

```
...
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + dbpath
...
```

When I compile 'build:release', I want to add this line to my python file:

```
...
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['POSTGRESQL_COLORFUL_URL']
...
```

edit: fixed typo in code and title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`grunt-sed`](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-sed).

It's a really useful 'find and replace' system that builds into Grunt.

#### From the docs:

```
npm install grunt-sed
```

Add this line to your project's Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sed');
```

Then in your build:dev and build:release tasks have the following:

```
sed: {
    database_uri: {
      path: 'path_to_your_python.py',
      pattern: '%PATTERN_IN_YOUR_PYTHON_FILE%',
      replacement: '\'sqlite:///\' + dbpath',
    }
  }
```

In your python file you want replacing you must also have `%PATTERN_IN_YOUR_PYTHON_FILE%` to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a plugin called grunt-string-replace that worked very well for what I needed to do. Also, I added some custom code in my Gruntfile.js to read different environment configurations and customize the build output based on that.

I detailed the full deployment script in this post: http://dev-blog.cloud-spinners.com/2014/02/complete-grunt-deployment-workflow-for.html

I hope you find that useful.